# How to post a new iOS App for a client

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

What steps should I take to post a new iOS app on the Apple Store for a client?  The steps below do not work.

1. Sign into developer.apple.com
2. Choose a team that a client has put me on
3. Click 'Submit and manage your apps on the App Store' (takes me to itunesconnect.apple.com)
4. Click 'My Apps'

After following these steps, I see a list of my own apps, not the client's.  How can I see a list of the client's apps rather than my own?

Comment: You need to sign into itunesconnect with the clients account details. itunesconnect doesn't share the same team functionality as developer.apple.com. Each team has 1 log in for itunesconnect and that's it.

Comment: Just to add to what Popeye said, you need to have an apple ID per business. So, if your customer is a company then you need to create a new id and get invited. If the customer is an individual then, as Popeye said, you need to access with the customer ID

Answer (score 0):

itunesconnect.apple.com and developer.apple.com are not connected.  So you need separate accounts on each system.  Using different email addresses for each makes things messy.  Turns out, that was my problem.

Solution: log into itunesconnect.apple.com and create the app separately.  If you have different email addresses for each system, don't try to click 'Submit and manage your apps on the App Store' from within developer.apple.com.